# Updating an array of objects with a resolved promise async await

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I am new to Javascript and I am running onto the following problem.

I have an array of objects, and I want one of the values of this object to be a resolved promise.

This is my array:

```
const businesslocationsaux  = [
      ...,
      {
        id: 1,
        type: 'Furniture',
        name: 'Colom Forever',
        address: 'Placa Pietat 5 Vic',
        image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472851294608',
        option_visited: false,
        option_promotion: false,
        latlng:{},
        distance: 0,
      },
      ...
]
```

Later on, I am using map to update all the objects in the array and have the latlng value be a resolved promise:

```
const businesslocations = businesslocationsaux.map( async obj => {
    const locationcoordinates = (await Location.geocodeAsync(obj.address))[0]
    console.log(locationcoordinates)
    return{
    ...obj,
    latlng: locationcoordinates,
}})

console.log(businesslocations)
```

When I console.log the location coordinates inside the asynchrounous function, I get an object, but when I try to retrieve my 'businesslocations' variable, it returns a promise.

What is the right way to do it?

Thank you soooo much for you help I am stuck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gonna have to use Promise.all and wait for it.

```js
 const businesslocations = await Promise.all(businesslocationsaux.map( async obj => {
        const locationcoordinates = (await Location.geocodeAsync(obj.address))[0]
        console.log(locationcoordinates)
        return{
        ...obj,
        latlng: locationcoordinates,
      }}))

      console.log(businesslocations)
```